# OCaml choose partial application parameter

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am making an http request using OCaml. To construct headers I have ended up with the following working code

```ml
let body =
  let headers = Header.init () in
  let headers =  Header.add headers "foo" "bar" in
  let uri = Uri.of_string "https://www.example.com/" in
  Client.get ~headers:headers uri >>= fun (resp, body) ->
  (* rest of client code irrelevant *)
```

However, lines 2 and 3 offend me (perhaps as I am very new to OCaml).

So I thought something like this would work, and be less offensive to my delicate sensibilities.

```ml
  let headers = Header.init |> Header.add "foo" "bar" in
```

However this fails to compile as the first arg for `Header.add` is expected to be of type `Header.t` and I provide a string. Is there a language feature to choose which args to partially apply? I have seen `flip` that can be found in Jane Street core and Batteries which would let me use the nicer syntax; however if I understand correctly this will flip all args and I will end up passing the value first instead of the key.

Is there any way to choose which arg to partially apply? For example in Scala we can produce a function using the 'placeholder' `_`;

```scala
val f1 = (v1: String, v2: String, v3: String) => 42
val f2 = f1("foo", _, "baz") // f2 is a String => Int
List("a", "b", "c").map(f1(_, "bar", "baz")) // this is fine.
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Just a minor side note: OCaml provides syntactic sugar for the very specific case where a label and its value have the same name. Hence, you can write `Client.get ~headers uri` instead of `Client.get ~headers:headers uri`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, these lines shouldn't really offend you, there is nothing wrong with this code, you're just refining the value of `header`. Imagine it is a history of the changes of the value. It is usually a bad idea to give different names to the same entity as it confusing (people who read your code may assume that you want the non-linear history of your value) and is error-prone (you can accidentally reference the wrong version of the entity).

With that said, when you have a long sequence of such assignments it becomes annoying (at least for its repetitiveness). In that case, I usually introduce a small DSL on the fly, e.g.,

```
let (:=) property value header = Header.add header property value
```

Now we can assign several properties, e.g.,

```
let setup = [
   "foo" := "bar";
   "joe" := "doe";
   ...
]
```

We now have a list of functions, and we can easily apply it to our header, with

```
let init_header cmds = List.fold cmds ~init:(Header.init ()) ~f:(|>)
```

Or, if we will put everything together,

```
let body = 
  let header = init_header [
   "foo" := "bar";
   "joe" := "doe";
  ] in
  ...
```

In this particular example, you can use just a list of pairs, instead of functions, e.g.,

```
 let header = init_header [
   "foo", "bar";
   "joe", "doe";
  ] in
```

But the approach with functions works better as it enables assigning values of different types, as long as at the end you can refine it to a function of type `header -> header`.

And as a bonus track, what we have just implemented is called a `Writer` monad :)

P.S.

> Is there any way to choose which arg to partially apply? For example in Scala we can produce a function using the 'placeholder' _;

Sure, use `fun`, e.g.,

```
  let headers = 
    Header.init () |> fun hdr -> 
    Header.add hdr "foo" "bar" |> fun hdr -> 
    Header.add hdr "joe" "doe" |> fun hdr ->
    ... in
```

or, if we will translate from Scala, then

```
val f2 = f1("foo", _, "baz")
```

will be

```
let f2 = fun x -> f1 "foo" x "baz"
```

or, even more shortly,

```
let f2 x = f1 "foo" x "baz"
```

Comment: Dear IVG, do you have any reference explaining " It is usually a bad idea to give different names to the same entity as it confusing" ? I've always considered that hiding local variables was error-prone.

Comment: It might be bad in imperative languages where variables stand for data locations. But with regular pure OCaml variables it the preferred style that is practiced by most if not all OCaml programmers. There is no place for error here, unless you're reusing the same name for different entities of course. It also helps the garbage collector to collect the old version as soon as possible as well as to the compiler to efficiently reuse registers and generate performant code. Finally, it reduces cognition burden by minimizing the state that you need to reason about.

Answer (score 2):

> However, lines 2 and 3 offend me

I believe that

```
let headers =  Header.add (Header.init ()) "foo" "bar" in
```

is more readable than your code. Otherwise, use different names, e.g.

```
let bareheaders = Header.init () in
let headers =  Header.add bareheaders "foo" "bar" in
```

Without knowing *which* HTTP library you use, I cannot explain the typing errors.

Did you consider using the [Ocsigen](https://ocsigen.org/home/intro.html) framework?

> Is there a language feature to choose which args to partially apply?

Maybe [labels](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.11/htmlman/lablexamples.html), or [classes](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.11/htmlman/advexamples.html), or [functors](https://ocaml.org/releases/4.11/htmlman/moduleexamples.html#s%3Afunctors)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the `Cohttp` module. You could define an auxiliary function `header` that builds a `Header.t` from a list of key/value pairs:

```
# let header = List.fold_left (fun h x -> (Cohttp.Header.add h (fst x) (snd x)))
                              (Cohttp.Header.init ());;
val header : (string * string) list -> Cohttp.Header.t = <fun>
```

This is the reverse of the existing `to_list` function (maybe it exists under a different name, I couldn't find it). Then you can use it as follows:

```
# Cohttp.Header.to_list (header [("h1","a");("h2","b")]);;
- : (string * string) list = [("h1", "a"); ("h2", "b")]
```